# How to make horizontal line thin in the CV?

Tags: cv

I am using a CV template available at the website of Overleaf: (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/your-new-cv/xqzhcmqkqrtw#.W5tHYqZKjIU).

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
    \textheight=700px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan (optional)
        \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}

\newcommand{\PersonalEntry}[2]{
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value

\newcommand{\SkillsEntry}[2]{      % Same as \PersonalEntry
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value    

\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Study
        \colorbox{Black}{%
            \parbox{6em}{%
            \hfill\color{White}#2}} \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\WorkEntry}[4]{               % Same as \EducationEntry
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Jobname
        \colorbox{Black}{\color{White}#2} \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par              % Company
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}

%%% Begin Document
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% you can upload a photo and include it here...
%\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
%   \vspace*{-2em}
%       \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{photo}
%\end{wrapfigure}

\MyName{Your Name}
\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae}

\sepspace

%%% Personal details
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Personal details}{}

\PersonalEntry{Birth}{January 1, 1980}
\PersonalEntry{Address}{111 First St, New York}
\PersonalEntry{Phone}{(123) 000-0000}
\PersonalEntry{Mail}{\url{me@home.com}}

%%% Education
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Education}{}

\EducationEntry{MSc. Name of Education}{2010-2012}{Name of
  University}{Descriptive text goes here. In order to maintain a stylish look, try to fill this description with a few lines of text. Do the same for the other entries in the education section.}
\sepspace

\EducationEntry{BSc. Name of Education}{2007-2010}{Name of University}{Descriptive text goes here. In order to maintain a stylish look, try to fill this description with a few lines of text. Do the same for the other entries in the education section.}

%%% Work experience
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Work experience}{}

\EducationEntry{Job name}{2011-present}{Company Name inc., Full-time}{Job description goes here. To maintain a stylish look, try to fill this description with a few lines of text. Do the same for the other entries in this section.}
\sepspace

\EducationEntry{Job name}{2010-2011}{Company Name inc., Part-time}{Job description goes here. To maintain a stylish look, try to fill this description with a few lines of text. Do the same for the other entries in this section.}

%%% Skills
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Skills}{}

\SkillsEntry{Languages}{Dutch (mother tongue)}
\SkillsEntry{}{English (fluent)}
\SkillsEntry{}{German (fluent)}

\SkillsEntry{Software}{\textsc{Matlab}, \LaTeX, \textsc{Ansys}, \textsc{Comsol}}


%%% References
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{References}{}
Available upon request
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a horizontal line at the beginning of each section. Is there any way to reduce the width of the horizontal line? 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Rather than linking to an external site please post the essential part of the code in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  External links can break in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the rule width setting, i.e.,

```
\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}} % LAST SPECIFICATION CHANGED TO 1pt
                                       % (ORIG. 3pt)
```

[image]